# PowerShell Form building

Tags: forms, powershell, scripting, textbox

I have built a pretty basic form for running New-ADUser and Add-AdGroupMember.

Right now I have it saved as a Function in psm1.

You bring up PS type the function name and the form loads on top of the powershell window. So far so good. But the users I have using it are wanting me to make the cursor active in the Textbox1 field automagically.

Anyone with an idea on somewhere I can find that info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the focus on the textbox object:

```
$textbox.Focus()
```

Comment: $textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
$textBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)
$textbox.CharacterCasing="Normal"
$textbox.Focused()
$form.Controls.Add($textBox)

Comment: Worked like a charm. This stuff is fantastic I just need to learn mroe of the terminology so google fu is easier.  Thanks a ton.

Comment: Well I say that, it worked while executing it from ISE as a ps1 but when I ran it as a function psm1 it did not switch focus.

Comment: You may need to add the `$textbox.focus()` to the form loaded event so that as soon as the form loads it switches the focus.

Comment: `$form.add_Loaded({  $textbox.Focus() })`